# Painting terrain - How to better to see the height differences to texture/place objects correctly?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, height-map

If I am in solid mode, in top down view I can somewhat make out the height differences. However, once I start painting the splatmap its impossible to make out where slopes are. Everything just looks flat since its being colored(would love to know how to turn this off in solid mode while texturing).

Does anyone have advice on how the view the height difference from top down view? I am really struggling creating scenes. I have to constantly adjust the camera, and redo a lot of work. Making a 10 minute task turn into well over an hour.

Thanks.

Comment: I added texturing based off slope, so that is a big help. If anyone has advice or tips I would appreciate it.